# SQL Query Get Last record Group by multiple fields

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a table with following fields:

```
ALERTID POLY_CODE ALERT_DATETIME ALERT_TYPE
```

I need to query above table for records in the last 24 hour.
Then group by POLY_CODE and ALERT_TYPE and get the latest Alert_Level value ordered by ALERT_DATETIME
I can get up to this, but I need the AlertID of the resulting records.
Any suggestions what would be an efficient way of getting this ?

I have created an SQL in SQL Server. See below

```
SELECT POLY_CODE, ALERT_TYPE, X.ALERT_LEVEL AS LAST_ALERT_LEVEL
FROM
(SELECT * FROM TableA where ALERT_DATETIME >= GETDATE() -1) T1
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [ALERT_LEVEL] 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM TableA where ALERT_DATETIME >= GETDATE() -1) T2 
    WHERE T2.POLY_CODE = T1.POLY_CODE AND
    T2.ALERT_TYPE = T1.ALERT_TYPE ORDER BY T2.[ALERT_DATETIME] DESC) X
GROUP BY POLY_CODE, ALERT_TYPE, X.[ALERT_LEVEL]

POLY_CODE       ALERT_TYPE      ALERT_LEVEL
04575       Elec        2
04737       Gas     3
06239       Elec        2
06552       Elec        2
06578       Elec        2
10320       Elec        2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select top 1 with ties *
from TableA
where ALERT_DATETIME >= GETDATE() -1
order by row_number() over (partition by POLY_CODE,ALERT_TYPE order by [ALERT_DATETIME] DESC)
```

The way this works is that for each group of POLY_CODE,ALERT_TYPE get their own row_number() starting from the most recent alert_datetime. Then, the `with ties` clause ensures that all rows(= all groups) with the row_number value of 1 get returned.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is creating a cte with the grouping that calculates the latesdatetime for each and then crosses it with the table to get the results. Just keep in mind that if there are more than one record with the same combination of poly_code, alert_type, alert_level and datetime they will all show.

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT ta.poly_code,ta.alert_type,MAX(ta.alert_datetime) AS LatestDatetime,
    ta.alert_level
FROM dbo.TableA AS ta
WHERE ta.alert_datetime >= DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY ta.poly_code, ta.alert_type,ta.alert_level
)
SELECT ta.*
FROM list AS l
INNER JOIN dbo.TableA AS ta ON ta.alert_level = l.alert_level AND ta.alert_type = l.alert_type AND ta.poly_code = l.poly_code AND ta.alert_datetime = l.LatestDatetime
```